# How to round floats in a nested list to 2 decimal places?

Tags: python, coordinates, rounding, nested-lists

I have coordinate lists of several polygons as listed below:

```
l_b =  [[[57.5, 2.875],
   [83.75, 4.1875],
   [83.75, 18.70923913043478],
   [57.50000000000001, 18.70923913043478],
   [57.5, 2.875]],
  [[83.75, 18.70923913043478],
   [57.50000000000001, 18.70923913043478],
   [57.5, 34.08695652173913],
   [83.75, 34.54347826086956],
   [83.75, 18.70923913043478]],
  [[0.0, 0.0],
   [18.125, 0.90625],
   [18.125, 16.70108695652174],
   [-2.530467720685112, 16.70108695652174],
   [0.0, 0.0]],
  [[18.125, 16.70108695652174],
   [-2.530467720685112, 16.70108695652174],
   [-5.0, 33.0],
   [18.125, 33.40217391304348],
   [18.125, 16.70108695652174]]]
```

How can I make all the numbers in list to round to 2 decimal places while keeping its format?

I've tried `l_b = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in l_b ]` but it's giving me `TypeError: must be real number, not list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *recursion* if your list is arbitrarily nested. If your list is 3 level nested then use @Guy's answer or @mrEvgenX's answer.

```
In [51]: def recur(lst):
    ...:     if isinstance(lst,float):
    ...:         return '%.2f'%lst #use round(lst,2) if you want float instead of string.
    ...:     else:
    ...:         return [recur(i) for i in lst]

In [52]: recur(l_b)
```

---

Output

```
[[['57.50', '2.88'],
  ['83.75', '4.19'],
  ['83.75', '18.71'],
  ['57.50', '18.71'],
  ['57.50', '2.88']],
 [['83.75', '18.71'],
  ['57.50', '18.71'],
  ['57.50', '34.09'],
  ['83.75', '34.54'],
  ['83.75', '18.71']],
 [['0.00', '0.00'],
  ['18.12', '0.91'],
  ['18.12', '16.70'],
  ['-2.53', '16.70'],
  ['0.00', '0.00']],
 [['18.12', '16.70'],
  ['-2.53', '16.70'],
  ['-5.00', '33.00'],
  ['18.12', '33.40'],
  ['18.12', '16.70']]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 levels of nested lists, so you need to drill down

```
l_b = [[['%.2f' % y[0], '%.2f' % y[1]] for y in x] for x in l_b]
```

Answer (score 4):

@Guy's solution has one side-effect. It makes list flatten.

This could be more suitable.

```
l_b = [[['%.2f' % z for z in y] for y in x] for x in l_b]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this numpy approach:

```
l_b = np.array( [[[57.5, 2.875],
   [83.75, 4.1875],
   [83.75, 18.70923913043478],
   [57.50000000000001, 18.70923913043478],
   [57.5, 2.875]],
  [[83.75, 18.70923913043478],
   [57.50000000000001, 18.70923913043478],
   [57.5, 34.08695652173913],
   [83.75, 34.54347826086956],
   [83.75, 18.70923913043478]],
  [[0.0, 0.0],
   [18.125, 0.90625],
   [18.125, 16.70108695652174],
   [-2.530467720685112, 16.70108695652174],
   [0.0, 0.0]],
  [[18.125, 16.70108695652174],
   [-2.530467720685112, 16.70108695652174],
   [-5.0, 33.0],
   [18.125, 33.40217391304348],
   [18.125, 16.70108695652174]]])
```

Shape of array is `(4,5,2)`

apply map to round the decimals upto 2 digits

```
a=list(map(lambda x :round(x,2),l_b.flatten() ))
```

convert back to original shape

```
np.array(a).reshape(4,5,2)
```

**or**

A much simpler way suggested by [Georgy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7851470/georgy)

```
l_b.round(2)
```

Comment: Too complicated and inefficient. You could just write `l_b.round(2)` instead.

Comment: @Georgy ,actuall I didn't know that it could be done in this way too,I will edit my answer

Comment: Also, it's important to note that this NumPy approach won't work with cases when polygons have a different number of vertices.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map()` with `round()`.  `round()` can take the desired number of digits as the second argument.

```py
for polygon in l_b:
    for point in polygon:
        point[:] = map(lambda x: round(x, 2), point)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `round` built-in function with list comprehension:

```
l_b = [[[round(e, 2) for e in j] for j in i] for i in l_b]
```